# Get Selected Dropdown value in JSP without form submit

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to get the selected value of a drop down from JS to JSP. Below is the code:

```
function testOnChange(){
    var type = jQuery("#rtl").val();
     <%
        final String contx = WCCA.getDoc("Proj");
     %>
     var newData = <%=contx%>;
  }
```

How do I get pass `type` to `getDoc()` method without form submit?

Comment: Are you trying to get the value from JS to JSP?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get from JS to JSP.

Comment: Have you successfully taken your value which is selected in the dropdown in JavaScript?

Comment: Are you trying to take the value on the same page or the next page?

Comment: Yes, I have successfully fetched the value and on the same page. I am calling the java method on the same page.